# Foursquare API only works locally

Tags: php, json, localhost, foursquare

I built an application on top of the foursquare API. It works perfectly on localhost but as soon as I upload it to a public website it stops working. I have checked to see if php is working by placing simple echos throughout my code and have had no issues. On my localhost I am able to echo information from the JSON the foursquare generates. When it is on the public server it echos nothing.

```
$urlgen = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near={$city}&query={$query}&client_id={$client_id}&client_secret={$client_secret}&v=20141015";
    $resultFour = fetchData($urlgen);
    echo "$resultFour";
```

This works code returns JSON on localhost but not on the website.

Fetch Data:

```
function fetchData($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch); 

         return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Any errors?  Could it be a CORS issue?

Comment: PHP and the console or not showing any errors.

Comment: Post the code for fetchData()

Comment: I updated the question with fetch data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your public server has curl installed (i assume that fethData use curl to connect to server). If you are sure that it is installed. For me works code:

```
private function fetchUrl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    $feedData = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);  
    return $feedData;
}
```

Comment: I am sure curl is installed and my fetchData($url) is the same as your fetchURL($url). If I echo $feedData on localhost it will return the JSON but not on the public server.

Comment: hm.. after curl_exec add curl_getinfo($ch), it will show you response returned by server. Then paste it here. edit: var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

Comment: change curl_exec if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}, on public server http_code = 0, it means that curl get no response,

Comment: and uncomment curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);